# Estoy creando una App de el clima y cuando intento pasar los datos me da el siguiente error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy creando una App de el clima y cuando intento pasar los datos me da el siguiente error

```
Context.jsx:22 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState') at getWeather
```

No se por que sucede y tampoco se si la manera correcta de pasar el state a otro componente es la correcta

```
import { wetherKey } from "../JS/Keya";
export const Context = createContext();
export const ContexProvider = (props) => {

 const  state = {
   temp: "",
   description: "",
   humidity: "",
   wind: "",
   city: "",
   country: "",
   error: null
 };
 const getWeather = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const cityValue = e.target.city.value,
     countryValue = e.target.country.value;
   const apiUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityValue}&appid=${wetherKey}&units=metric&lang=sp`;
   const apiResponse = await fetch(apiUrl);
   const data = await apiResponse.json();
   
 this.setState({
   temp: data.main.temp,
   description: data.weather[0].description,
   humidity: data.main.humidity,
   wind: data.wind.speed,
   city: data.name,
   country: data.sys.country,
   error: null
 });

 };
 //pasar el state y la funcion getWeather al provider
 return (
   <Context.Provider
     value={{
       getWeather: getWeather,
       ...state
     }}
   >
     {props.children}
   </Context.Provider>
 );
};
```

Comment: 1 - Tu componente es una función de flecha por ende, una función de flecha no tiene su propio valor `this`. En su lugar, utiliza el valor `this` del ámbito léxico (el padre de la funcion).
2 - Un compnente funcional no hace uso de setState, en su lugar hace use de `hooks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modificaria tu código de la siguiente manera:

- Modificando la variable state para así utilizar el hook `useState`.
- Reemplazaría el uso de `this.setState` que pertenece un método para un componente de clase por el uso de `setState`.
- Y por ultimo solo queda utilizar la variable que contiene tu estado `estado`.

**PD: Utilice las variables `estado` y `setEstado` por no crearte una confusión, de igual manera las puedes renombrar como gustes**

---

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const Context = createContext();

export const ContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [estado, setEstado] = useState({
    temp: '',
    description: '',
    humidity: '',
    wind: '',
    city: '',
    country: '',
    error: null,
  });

  const getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const cityValue = e.target.city.value,
      countryValue = e.target.country.value;
    const apiUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${panama}&appid=${df6d14fdcdbbcffc10c143824316f638}&units=metric&lang=sp`;
    const apiResponse = await fetch(apiUrl);
    const data = await apiResponse.json();

    setEstado({
      temp: data.main.temp,
      description: data.weather[0].description,
      humidity: data.main.humidity,
      wind: data.wind.speed,
      city: data.name,
      country: data.sys.country,
      error: null,
      ...estado,
    });
  };
  //pasar el state y la funcion getWeather al provider
  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        getWeather: getWeather,
        ...estado,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Te dejo por acá el playground para que lo revices

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5fu52r?file=src/ContextProvider.js